# wait for foreach to finish before executing next lines

Tags: javascript, firebase

I want the code to wait for the foreach function to complete before going to the next line to perform the if statement on the counter number. I am sure I have to put a Promise somewhere... but I also thought that .then() would do the trick?

It appears there are examples of this but I am not able to figure this one out or where Im going wrong here:

```
      async getSomeData () {
        
            const data = [];
            const ref = fire.firestore();
            
        
            ref
            .collection(‘foo’)
            .where(‘open’, '==', true)
            .get()
            .then(async snapshot => {
               let count = 0;
               snapshot
                .docs
                .forEach(async doc => {
                  const {foo, bar} = doc.data();
                  const number_count = await this.getNumber(doc.id);
        
                  if (number_count >= 1){
                    count++;
                    data.push({
                      foo,
                      bar
                    });
        
                  this.setState({
                    data : data,
                });
              }
            })
        
    .then() ?????
          **//THIS IS EXECUTING BEFORE THE FOREACH FINISHES** 
    
              if(count==0){
                this.setState({
                  isLoading: false,
                  noStores: true
                  });
          }
        
        
        
          }).catch(error => {
              console.log(error);
        
                //if fails
                this.setState({
                  noStores : true,
              });
            });
        
          };
```

Appreciate any help I can get. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please format the code?

Comment: Await inside of a forEach lambda doesn't pause the loop.  Your `then` callback needs to return another promise that resolves only after all promises from the foreach loop are resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you're using `async`, the `await` keyword essentially replaces `.then`.  In other words:

```
ref
        .collection(‘foo’)
        .where(‘open’, '==', true)
        .get()
        .then(async snapshot => {
        // indented code that uses snapshot
```

can become:

```
const snapshot = await ref
        .collection(‘foo’)
        .where(‘open’, '==', true)
        .get();
// not-indented code that uses snapshot
```

When you use `await` in this way the browser *will* pause your code and "restart it" when the request returns, the *exact same* way as with `.then` (because it's literally just syntactic sugar on top of promises).

Second, as @Doug Stevenson noted in a comment, `forEach` doesn't pause on promises, so when doing asynchronous work what you really want to do is use `map` instead of a `forEach`, and combine it with `Promise.all`, like so:

```
await Promise.all(someArray.map(async x => ...))
```

In other words, you want your (formerly) `forEach` callback to return a promise, and `map` lets you do that (vs. `forEach` returns nothing).  `Promise.all` will convert each of those individual promises into one big one, which you can then `await` or chain a `.then` off.

When that big promise resolves (either with `.then` or `await`) it will have an array as a resolved value, and that array will contain all of the resolved values from the original promises.  In other words if you do:

```
const foo = await Promise.all(arrayOfPromises);
```

then `foo` will be an array containing what *would have* been passed as the `.then`/`await` value for each of the promises in the passed-in `arrayOfPromises`.

Answer (score 0):

javascript code, by default will finish before moving on to the next line. That's its natural behavior. It you just write code normally it will execute one line at a time.

you have added a "async" tag to you code and then asked for it to not run in an async way, which is note entirely logical.

if you want your code to execute in a way that it finishes the foreach, simply don't add any async tags.